# Insert into Xamarin NSMutableArray<T> results in out of range exception

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

This code works:

```
var arr = new NSMutableArray();
arr.Insert(new NSString("lol"), 0);
```

But this causes `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`

```
var arr = new NSMutableArray<NSString>();
arr.Insert(new NSString("lol"), 0);
```

Same goes to InsertObjects method:

```
var arr = new NSMutableArray<NSString>(); // Crash
//var arr = new NSMutableArray(); - No crash
var srcArr = new NSString[] { new NSString("one"), new NSString("two") };
var indexes = NSIndexSet.FromNSRange(new NSRange(0, 2));

arr.InsertObjects(srcArr, indexes);
```

Maybe there are some other methods that don't work. Why is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support I think this is a type 3 question. *I got this error and I'm sure it's a bug*. I just can provide a workaround and I think you should add this to the bug tracker. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Can't do, bugzilla won't send me password recovery email. So it's up to community I guess. As for workaround, well, I guess just don't use NSMutableArray<T>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me. I can't find anything on the bugtracker.

The workaround would be to use `Add` if the index is equal to `Count`. You could pack this into a extension method like:

```
public static class NSMutableArrayFix
{
    public static void InsertFix<T>(this NSMutableArray<T> array, T obj, nint index)
        where T : class, INativeObject
    {
        if(array.Count == (nuint)index)
        {
            array.Add(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            array.Insert(obj, index);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use

```
var arr = new NSMutableArray<NSObject>();
arr.InsertFix(new NSString("lol"), 0);
```

Comment: Added more info on other method to the question